# Sum of Digits of the Input from user

Tags: java

I want to create a code that will get the sum of all the digits of the input,
*sample input: 241 sample output: 7*
But there are restrictions in in making the program, only the basic operations, functions should be used and no string function is to be used in getting the said sum of the digits only (loop, /, %, *,-,+)are allowed to be used.

The program I am thinking should start with this..

```
 public class SumOfDigits{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = input.nextInt();

        while(){

        }
  }
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you stuck? Or... what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use a modulus trick to isolate, and then sum, each digit in the input number:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = input.nextInt();
int sum = 0;

while (num > 0) {
    sum += num % 10;
    num /= 10;
}
```

Follow the link below for a working demo.

### Demo

Comment: @ScaryWombat Another user also posted this same answer (1 minute later).  You should also comment him ^ ^

Comment: Is it good think to give him solution directly ? He did not try anything to solve, just wrote a Scanner only. Also he can find same question in SO.

Comment: @drowny Sadly, most of the question I see coming onto the site these days are of _lower_ quality than this.  At least there was a skeleton code.

Comment: Yes, you are right on this situations. But you and which person is same as your level should be more restrictive on SO questions. That was a skeleton code , but maybe you did homework of him.  Not a good i think just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

modulu 10 of the number will give you the last digit, the dividing it by 10 will give you the other digits, due to integer division. You can loop until you've handled all the digits:

```
int sum = 0;
while (num != 0) {
    sum += (num % 10);
    num /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Not defined what should happen with negative numbers, but would `while (num > 0) {` be better?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a recursive function like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    Scanner scanner ;
    int result = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // initialize new instance of current class
        Main thisIns = new Main();

        // initialize scanner instance for this instance
        thisIns.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


        //calling for getting user inputs
        int i = thisIns.getUserInput();

        //get the sum of the integer
        thisIns.getSumOfInterger(i, 0);



        System.out.println("result  is " + thisIns.result);

    }

    public int getUserInput(){
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer : ");
        int i = scanner.nextInt();
        return i;
    }

    public void getSumOfInterger(int i, int moduler) {

        if (i != 0) {
            moduler += i%10;
            getSumOfInterger(i/10, moduler);
//            return 0;
        }else{
            result = moduler;
        }
    }
}
```